# Apache Redirect https://www fails with ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the next .htaccess file, and everything works, except when I try to access https:// wwww. example.com

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

#my rule to remove www from all requests => it doesn't work
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www. example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect everything from port 80 to 443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?task=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?task=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?task=$1&business_slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^business/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?task=$1&category=$2&slug=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^detail/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^listing/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

#category pages
RewriteRule ^category(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

With the file above, I get all redirects working, except from https:// www. example.com to https :// example.com.

***I added some white spaces in links because I couldn't post more than two links in question, without a reputation.***

Comment: Did you find what happened? I encounter the same issue...

Comment: Did you also have to add whitespace between `https://` and `example.com$`? It should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`. (twice)